# CLion not detecting cmake in WSL

Tags: clion, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to run the WSL toolchain on my Windows PC and have configured my WSL to run an SSH server, installed cmake etc. I am able to connect to the WSL SSH but for some reason CLion is not detecting the WSL cmake.

[image]

Any idea how I can go about fixing this ?

Comment: What about wrong path separators (`\ ` vs `/`). Will it work if you specify correct ones?

Comment: I already tried that, had no effect

Comment: Which version of CLion do you use?

Comment: I am using 2018.2

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the zsh shell! Try the standard bash. Perhaps it helps.